# Create array of associated arrays with same key using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is code that produces the array of associated arrays that I need to input into a PHPWord cloneBlock() routine.

```
// Start with 2 associative arrays, both having the same key
$array1 = array('course' => 'Text1');
$array2 = array('course' => 'Text2');
// create an array of arrays
$my_arrays = array($array1, $array2);
```

The array of associated arrays result looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["course"]=>
    string(5) "Text1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["course"]=>
    string(5) "Text2"
  }
}
```

Now I want to produce the same result but in a loop as I do not know how many associated arrays will be in my main array.

I have tried array_merge() but that gets rid of elements that have duplicate keys.

Also tried array_merge_recursive() but that takes the keys out of the inner arrays and puts it outside & puts numeric keys into the inner arrays.

Is there another way to create the result I am after?

I have put my failed attempts here:
https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/4e2b3b2

Comment: $my_arrays[] = array("foo" => "bar");

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here - can't see how this will allow a loop or generate the structure I am after...

Comment: My apologies Salman - that is actually exactly correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
//init your array
$my_arrays = [];
//push first array
$my_arrays[] = $array1;
//push second array
$my_arrays[] = $array2;
//push xxx array
//push first array
$my_arrays[] = $xxx;
//and go on
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the [] was the bit I was missing - I never even knew about it! I have modified my code in the PHP Sandbox to include code that works for my sample with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell this gives the desired output:

```
$result = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    array_push($result, array('course' => "Text$i"));
}
$result = array_merge($result, array());
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [course] => Text0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [course] => Text1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [course] => Text2
        )

)
```